# Conditional for single-{post-type}.php

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-tags, single

Please help with this code for custom post type "video":

```
If is single-video.php page {

     list custom-taxonomy of video. Example actors

} Else { do nothing }
```

I´m tried with is_single, is_singular, is_page_template but imposible.

Answer (score 31):

According to the [WordPress conditional docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) it should be:

```
if ( is_singular( 'video' ) ) {
     // do conditional stuff

} else {
     //do other stuff
}
```

Also if you want a blank page or no content to show when the CPT is not video you don't really need the `else` so you could omit it. You could ALSO do something like:

```
if ( ! is_singular( 'video' ) ) {
     // do nothing

} else {
     //do conditional stuff
}
```